# Repeated measure ANOVA vs. random-coefficient models

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, random-effects-model

A large cohort of freshly diagnosed patients is randomly assigned to one out of two treatment regimens in a balanced design. During a fixed time frame blood samples are drawn at set, unequally spaced time points and multiple blood test results are used as outcomes. It is known that in any case, there will be disease-independent change of blood test results correlated with time (e.g., because of aging), but I want to know if this change differs significantly between the two subject groups. At the start of the treatment, the subjects have different disease scores, and of course there is a large number of possible confounders (age, sex, comorbidity etc.).

Because the design of the study is balanced, the number of time points is small and for most subjects, we have the same number of blood drawings, my first thought was to use repeat-measure ANOVA. However, there are some missing values, and the time spacing between blood draws for a single subject isn't equal (but it is approximately equal between subjects).

After doing some literature research, I found an article (Locascio and Atri, 2011) describing different statistical methods for longitudinal studies, and now I feel that a random-coefficient model would be more appropriate.

Is it true that repeat-measure ANOVA is inappropriate in this case or are there ways to correct for the unequal time spacing and to handle missing data? Which additional assumptions do I have to test? Which method would you recommend in the given situation? Is there anything else to consider?